# Dynamically add method to class from property function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I think a code sample will better speak for itself:

```
class SomeClass:
    example = create_get_method()
```

Yes, that's all – ideally.

In that case, `create_get_method` would add a `get_example()` to `SomeClass` in a way that it can be accessed via an instance of `SomeClass`:

```
obj = SomeClass()
obj.get_example() <- returns the value of self.example
```

(Of course, the idea is to implement a complex version of `get_contact`, that's why I want to do that in a non-repetitive way, and this is a simplified version that represents well the issue.)

I don't know if that's possible, because it require to have access to the property name (`example`) and the class (`SomeClass`) since these can not be guessed in advance (that function will be used on many and various classes).

I know it's something possible, because that's kind of what SQLAlchemy does with their `relationship()` function on a class:

```
class Model(BaseModel):
    id = ...
    contact_id = db.Integer(db.ForeignKey..)
    contact = relationship('contact') <-- This !
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Hard to tell what you're asking for, but dataclasses seem close https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html Ideally, you don't need getters/property functions for simply accessing a class attribute

Comment: Are you looking for auto-generated properties?

Comment: Please post an actual [mcve] that illustrates what you want. The placeholder names may be very clear in your head, but it's not clear what you think they should do.

Comment: @MadPhysicist If I can rephrase the question : Can I access the class and the key from the function `create_get_method` in order to modify the class and add a bound method based on the key (`example` here)? Does this makes more sense?

Comment: It sounds like you want `create_get_method()` to be a `@classmethod` so that its first argument is the current class.   You can add methods to instances (though it's discouraged).  I don't know if you can add methods to classes and automatically have it inherited by all instances of the class.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Give us the big picture, not your implementation.

Comment: This would be much easier if you made an actual toy example. It looks like you want a descriptor similar to a property, but I can't be sure

Comment: For example, what is get_contact? How it it going to be repetitive? I feel like you're leaving out the really important info here

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's really just like the `relationship` of SQLAlchemy, excepted that instead of making that field available as a field, it would create a function on the method. The reason is that `relationship` is sync and I'm trying to find a solution that would work with async (AsyncSession at SQLAlchemy), so creating a function, that is a coroutine, would be possible. It's not (yet) a good idea to have an async attribute in python.

Comment: "Of course, the idea is to implement a complex version of `get_contact`" — what's `get_contact`? What "property name" are you talking about?

Comment: Do you actually want a [``property``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) (as the text says) or just a getter/method (as the code shows)? Does the "magic property" have to derive the name ``get_example`` from being assigned to just ``example``, or are you fine assigning to ``get_example`` directly?

Comment: "The reason is that relationship is sync and I'm trying to find a solution that would work with async" Note that properties can be ``async`` for lookup. Only setting and deleting must be sync.

Answer (score 1):

Objects bound to class-level variables can have [a `__set_name__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set_name__) that will be called immediately after the class object has been created. It will be called with two arguments, the class object, and the name of the variable the object is saved as in the class.

You could use this to create your extra getter method, though I'm not sure why exactly you want to (you could make the object a descriptor instead, which would probably be better than adding a separate getter function to the parent class).

```
class create_get_method:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        def getter(self):
            return getattr(self, name)

        getter_name = f"get_{name}"
        getter.__name__ = getter_name
        setattr(owner, getter_name, getter)

    # you might also want a __get__ method here to give a default value (like None)
```

Here's how that would work:

```
>>> class Test:
...    example = create_get_method()
...    

>>> t = Test()

>>> print(t.get_example())
<__main__.create_get_method at 0x000001E0B4D41400>

>>> t.example = "foo"

>>> print(t.get_example())
foo
```

You could change the value returned by default (in the first `print` call), so that the `create_get_method` object isn't as exposed. Just add a `__get__` method to the `create_get_method` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a custom non-data descriptor, like a property, except that you don't need a `__set__` method:

```
class ComplicatedDescriptor:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, owner, type):
        # Here, `owner` is the instance of `SomeClass` that contains this descriptor
        # Use `owner` to do some complicated stuff, like DB lookup or whatever
        name = f'_{self.name}'

        # These two lines for demo only
        value = owner.__dict__.get(name, 0)
        value += 1

        setattr(owner, name, value)
        return value
```

Now you can have any number of classes that use this descriptor:

```
class SomeClass:
    example = ComplicatedDescriptor('example')
```

Now you can do something like:

```
>>> inst0 = SomeClass()
>>> inst1 = SomeClass()
>>> inst0.example
1
>>> inst1.example
1
>>> inst1.example
2
>>> inst0.example
2
```

The line `name = f'_{self.name}` is necessary because the descriptor here is a non-data descriptor: it has no `__set__` method, so if you create `inst0.__dict__['example']`, the lookup will no longer happen: `inst0.example` will return `inst0.__dict__['example']` instead of calling `SomeClass.example.__get__(inst0, type(inst0))`. One workaround is to store the value under the attribute name `_example`. The other is to make your descriptor into a data descriptor:

```
class ComplicatedDescriptor_v2:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, owner, type):
        # Here, `owner` is the instance of `SomeClass` that contains this descriptor
        # Use `owner` to do some complicated stuff, like DB lookup or whatever

        # These two lines for demo only
        value = owner.__dict__.get(self.name, 0)
        value += 1

        owner.__dict__[self.name] = value
        return value

    def __set__(self, *args):
        raise AttributeError(f'{self.name} is a read-only attribute')
```

The usage is generally identical:

```
class SomeClass:
    example = ComplicatedDescriptor_v2('example')
```

Except that now you can't accidentally override your attribute:

```
>>> inst = SomeClass()
>>> inst.example
1
>>> inst.example
2
>>> inst.example = 0
AttributeError: example is a read-only attribute
```

Descriptors are a fairly idiomatic way to get and set values in python. They are preferred to getters and setters in almost all cases. The simplest cases are handled by the built-in `property`. That being said, if you wanted to explicitly have a getter method, I would recommend doing something very similar, but just returning a method instead of calling `__get__` directly.

For example:

```
def __get__(self, owner, type):
    def enclosed():
        # Use `owner` to do some complicated stuff, like DB lookup or whatever
        name = f'_{self.name}'

        # These two lines for demo only
        value = owner.__dict__.get(name, 0)
        value += 1

        setattr(owner, name, value)
        return value
    return enclosed
```

There is really no point to doing something like this unless you plan on really just want to be able to call `inst.example()`.

Comment: "property, except that you don't need a __set__ method" Isn't that what ``property`` provides by default anyway?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi. Property always has a set method, it just doesn't set anything by default